# Querying tables based on other column values

Tags: sql

Is there a way to query different databases based on the value of a column in the query?

Say for example you have the following columns:

- id
- part_id
- attr_id
- attr_value_ext
- attr_value_int

You then run a query and if the attr_id is '1' is returns the attr_value_int column but if attr_id is greater than '1' it joins data from another table based on the attr_value_ext.

Comment: Do you mean that the other table varies depending on the value of attr_value_ext? If so how many possibilities are there?

Comment: Hmm, four answers, all completely different from each other.  You do need to give more detail.  Some sample input and expected output would be a good start.

Comment: Is there a particular database you're targeting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

something like this?

```
select case when a.id = 1 then a.attr_value_int
            when a.id > 1 then b.some_other_col
            else null end as whatever
from first_table a
     left outer join other_table b
     on ( a.attr_val_ext = b.id )
/
```

Comment: Yup, just like that. I'll have to give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a conditional in the `on` clause, like:

```
select    case when attr_id = 1 then attr_value_int
               when attr_id = 2 then t1.value_int
               when attr_id = 3 then t2.value_int
          end
from      YourTable yt
left join Table1 t1 
on        t1.attr_id = 2 and yt.part_id = t1.part_id
left join Table2 t2 
on        t1.attr_id = 3 and yt.part_id = t2.part_id
```

This will work best if the number of tables is relatively small, and known in advance.  Otherwise you'll have to resort to dynamic SQL, or building a follow up query from the client.

Comment: Was the second join supposed to be to Table2?

Answer (score 1):

hard to give an exact answer based on that description...

you should be able to do that with a UNION

```
select stuff from one table where attr_id = 1
UNION
select stuff from another table where attr_id > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in the SQL spec, but there are often DB specific functions that will do this for you.  For example, decode on oracle would work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID,PART_ID,ATTR_ID,CASE
  WHEN attr_id =1 THEN attr_value_int  
  WHEN attr_id >1 THEN <SELECT QUERY>
  END <My Column>
from TABLE;
```

Maybe this will work